# Select from another table based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server and SQL queries. These are my three tables:

[image]

**Primary keys**

- Table 1: CaseId
- Table 2: ID
- Table 3: parentId

In table 3 - if the parent is a father then the status code is **8** and if the parent is a mother then the status code is **10**

I want to write a select query where I can get an output like the following:

[image]

Please help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Specify the expected result, when having the above table data.

Comment: @jarlh I update the question with the expected results

Comment: don't use image  .. posta data sample as text  ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join twice both tables table2 and table3:

```
select 
  t1.caseid, t1.caseName,
  t3f.name fathername, t3f.email fatheremail,
  t3m.name mothername, t3m.email motheremail
from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2f  on t2f.caseId = t1.caseId
inner join table3 t3f on t3f.parentid = t2f.parentid and t3f.gendercode=8
left join table2 t2m  on t2m.caseId = t1.caseId
inner join table3 t3m on t3m.parentid = t2m.parentid and t3m.gendercode=10
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ee8284283c67b8e9907fa27bafe82ccc)

Comment: This works..Thank you very much.As I am new to sql queries as i think this question header is also not suitable if you can just give me a suggestion for this qs it would be so appreciated , thanks

Comment: It is not always easy to create suitable titles. Maybe something like: "Join 3 tables under conditions..."

Comment: Got it Thanks..!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use two sub queries from Table3 where one is for father and the other is for mother. then you can join them with case and case-parent mapping tables to get the desired output,

```
SELECT
    C.CaseID, C.CaseName, F.Name AS FatherName, F.Email AS FatherEmail,
    M.Name AS MotherName, M.Email AS MotherEmail
FROM
    Table1 C
INNER JOIN 
    Table2 CP C.CaseID = CP.CaseID
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM TABLE3 WHERE GENDERCODE = 8) F ON F.ParentID = CP.ParentID
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM TABLE3 WHERE GENDERCODE = 10) M ON M.ParentID = CP.ParentID
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,I tried this but its giving null record..is it because of my data problem? if i use left outer instead of inner then there is a output but duplicate records

Comment: For which column you are getting null?

Comment: I mean output is 0 rows

Answer (score 1):

you can use conditional aggregation with case when expression

```
select caseid,casename,max(case when gendercode=8 then name end) as fathername
MAX(case when gendercode=8 then email end) as fatheremail,
MAX(case when gendercode=10 then name end) as mothername,
MAX(case when gendercode=10 then email end) as motheremail
from
(
select b.caseid,c.casesname,gendercode,name,email
from table3 a inner join table2 b on a.parentid=b.parentid
inner join table1 c on b.caseid=c.caseid
)A group by caseid,casename
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `join`s but it is a little more complicated than you might expect.  A CTE helps:

```
with p as (
      select t2.caseid, t3.*
      from table2 t2 join
           table3 t3
           on t2.parentid = t3.parentid
     )
select t1.*,
       f.name as fathername, f.email as fatheremail
       m.name mothernaem, m.email as motheremail        
from table1 t1 left join
     p pf
     on t1.caseid = pf.caseid and pf.gendercode = 8 left join
     p pm
     on t1.caseid = pm.caseid and pm.gendercode = 10;
```

That said, conditional aggregation as proposed by fa06 also works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like following. To combine two rows (mother and father), you can use `MAX` aggregate function using `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT caseid, 
       casename, 
       Max(fathername)  AS fathername, 
       Max(fatheremail) AS fatheremail, 
       Max(mothername)  AS mothername, 
       Max(motheremail) AS motheremail 
FROM   (SELECT t1.caseid, 
               t1.casename, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN gendercode = 8 THEN t3.NAME 
                 ELSE NULL 
               END AS fathername, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN gendercode = 8 THEN t3.email 
                 ELSE NULL 
               END AS fatheremail, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN gendercode = 10 THEN t3.NAME 
                 ELSE NULL 
               END AS mothername, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN gendercode = 10 THEN t3.email 
                 ELSE NULL 
               END AS motheremail 
        FROM   table1 t1 
               INNER JOIN table2 t2 
                       ON t1.caseid = t2.caseid 
               INNER JOIN table3 t3 
                       ON t2.parentid = t2.parentid 
        WHERE  t3.gendercode IN( 8, 10 ))t 
GROUP  BY caseid, 
          casename
```